# How to decode an ethers js Uint8Array?

Tags: solidity, ethers.js

Say I have a Uint8Array of length 32(i.e. 256 bits) how do I decode that array based on type. For example `abi.encode(-100)` as a byte array is `Array(31).fill(255).concat([9])` which can also be expressed as the following hexstring: `0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff9c`.

How do I decode the (32 bytes)byte array in ethers js by specifying its type for generic solidity types? The [ether js documentation](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/bytes/) discussing byte arrays doesn't explain how to decode it.

Decoding the byte array should return the input value to `abi.encode` for the following functions.

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract AbiEncode {

    function encodeUint16(uint16 _uint16) public pure returns (bytes memory){
        // abi.encode(100) == 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000064
        return abi.encode(_uint16);
    }

    function encodeInt16(int16 _int16) public pure returns (bytes memory){
        // abi.encode(-100) == 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff9c
        return abi.encode(_int16);
    }

    function encodeAddress(address _address) public pure returns (bytes memory){
        // abi.encode(0xf8e81D47203A594245E36C48e151709F0C19fBe8) == 0x000000000000000000000000f8e81d47203a594245e36c48e151709f0c19fbe8
        return abi.encode(_address);
    }

    function encodeBool(bool _bool) public pure returns (bytes memory){
        // abi.encode(true) == 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
        return abi.encode(_bool);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to get it working thanks in part to [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/110498/86303).

```js
import {
  utils
} from 'ethers'; // v5.5.4

// returnBytesArray is of type Uint8Array where each 32 bytes encodes a single value
const returnHexString = utils.hexlify(returnBytesArray); 

const decodedRetVal = utils.defaultAbiCoder.decode(
  ['int16'], // specify your return type/s here
  utils.hexDataSlice(returnHexString, 0)
);
```