# Multisend token details not available in Safe

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis, safe-core-sdk

[image]in a multisend tx is there a way to fetch which tx has which currency as the data fetched through safe API and safe SDK only provides that it is a multisend tx and whom are you sending to and what is the amount but not the type of token/currency

[image]
How does Safe shows all the token and the amount in their UI.

Answer (score 1):

Each item in `multiSend` is unique txn. You can identify the token, amount and address receiving the funds by decoding the calldata. A simpler way to decode this for all txn's that have `value != 0` and `data==nil` can be considered as eth transfers. For erc20 transfers decode them using erc20-abi. An example on how to use ethers can be found here: [How to decode input data in ethersjs](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/110489/how-to-decode-input-data-in-ethersjs)

Comment: Please have a look at the edited ques.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the content of a transaction, you indeed need to decode the transaction data. As with Safe{Wallet} UI, you can check the open [source code](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-wallet-web/tree/main) to understand how it is displayed, especially [here](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-wallet-web/blob/369e90421978370a37042478005c8c3d253d724e/src/utils/transaction-calldata.ts) to see how calldata is decoded, and [here](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-wallet-web/blob/369e90421978370a37042478005c8c3d253d724e/src/components/transactions/TxDetails/TxData/index.tsx) to see how it is rendered.

Hope it helps,
Louis